# SharePoint 2013 Calendar presentation configuration (not showing events in Outlook style view

Tags: 2013, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

How do I make the calendar entries come up in the tabs of the calendar (first screenshot)? I can make it come up just as lines of records (second screenshot), but not entirely sure why the same data refuses to show in the calendar tabs?

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]